# Trying to launch ruby app using capistrano, keep getting libicudata.so.48 is missing, what package?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos7, capistrano3

libicudata.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am running centos 7 64bit addition. I have looked at dozens of packages, but after a dozen install and 20 reboots I am still getting this error message.

```
    ibicudata.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.3/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so (LoadError)
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.3/lib/charlock_holmes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/gitlab-grit-2.8.1/lib/grit.rb:79:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Does running `gem pristine charlock_holmes` help?

Comment: No, I found that earlier and did not help.

Comment: Restored charlock_holmes-0.7.3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Restored charlock_holmes-0.7.5

Comment: I take that back, that time it did and now I get /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.3/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6icu_488ByteSinkE

Comment: It looks like there's an open issue regarding that: https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes/issues/31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get this error, it usually indicates that the ABI of a library that a Ruby Gem C extension uses changed, usually due to a system update.

In this case, the libicudata library probably got updated, and then charlock_holmes, which dynamically links to it, needs a recompile so that the symbols match up again. This is one of the tricky bits of using rvm or rbenv.